# Cannot Access Key of Document in Firstore Node

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I write to the Firestore after creating a user, as coded below:

```
                userMap.put("email", user.getEmail());
                userMap.put("display_name", user.getDisplayName());
                userMap.put("user_id", user.getUid());
                userMap.put("provider", user.getProviders());
                mStoreBaseRef.collection(USERS).add(userMap);
```

When this user is written to the Firestore, a unique ID is generated for that User.

Later on, I want to write to the user node, however I do not have the unique key that was generated. I query the "Users" node based on a specific ID of a user so that I can write to that node, but I am unsure how to obtain the key for that specific user:

```
Query x = mStoreBaseRef.collection(USERS_LABEL).whereEqualTo("user_id", mPollCreatorID);
                x.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot d : task.getResult()){
                            User user = d.toObject(User.class);
                            Log.v("USER", user.getUser_id());
                            //I need to add the document here of the unique key
                            mStoreBaseRef.collection(USERS_LABEL).add(followersMap);
                        }
                    }
```

I am trying to obtain mAQGM9S.......from below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They ID of a document is available through [`DocumentSnapshot.getId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getId()). So:

```
Query x = mStoreBaseRef.collection(USERS_LABEL).whereEqualTo("user_id", mPollCreatorID);
x.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        for (DocumentSnapshot d : task.getResult()){
            Log.v("ID", d.getId());
            User user = d.toObject(User.class);
            Log.v("USER", user.getUser_id());
            //I need to add the document here of the unique key
            mStoreBaseRef.collection(USERS_LABEL).add(followersMap);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the `push id` of that document. For that, you should use `getId()` method. Here is how you can do that :

```
    Query x = mStoreBaseRef.collection(USERS_LABEL).whereEqualTo("user_id", mPollCreatorID);
    x.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot d : task.getResult()){
                User user = d.toObject(User.class);
                //Getting push id
                String pushId = d.getId();
                Log.v("USER", pushId);

                //... 
            }
        }
```

Try it and let us know if it's working or not.